# Kernel Panic при загрузке ОС (Red Hat)

Tags: linux, kernel, redhat

Сервер с ОС - Red Hat.
Ядро 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64

Сервер крутится на VmWare.
Работал нормально, но внезапно, на утро, перестал пускать пользователя. Решил перезагрузить сервер. После перезагрузки сервер выпал в Kernel Panic.

Конфиг grub.conf

```
root (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=357f520e-d03a-4990-996b-06b24ac965bb rd_NO_LUKS KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us LANG-en_US.UTF-8 rd_NOMD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_NO_LVM biosdevname=0rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64.img
```

По логам загрузки видно, что проблема с SELinux. [image: Loading SELinux policy] ,

Хотя файл load_policy на месте.

```
[root@localhost sbin]# ls -la | grep load_
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 11216 Mar 6 06:04 load_policy
```

Если отключить при загрузке ядра SELinux, то падает в новую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да и по факту, читал, что не имеет смысла отключать SELinux.

Нашел [похожую проблему с xen](http://lists.xen.org/archives/html/xen-users/2013-01/msg00337.html), но я не совсем осознал, как он это решил. Если кто-нибудь переведет на пальцах, буду благодарен.

Update:
[image: chroot]

Update2:
[image: bash.static]

Update3:
[image: bash.static.ldd]

Update4:
[image: fstab]

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, закрывать (и спорить по этому поводу) [не стоит](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (по ссылке есть слова, что вопросы по администрированию ОС разрешены). А где еще человеку решить свою проблему?

Comment: @avp хм, да действительно, вероятно этот список поменялся недавно, либо я его невнимательно прочитал (наивно полагая, что он эквивалентен оригинальному SO). Ну раз разрешено, то нет вопросов, прошу прощения.

Comment: `root=UUID=357f520e-d03a-4990-996b-  06b24ac965bb` — там на самом деле пробел (даже два) или это ошибка копирования?

Comment: Вот человек [пишет](http://marc.info/?l=xen-users&m=135907220030809) о решении похожей проблемы `because some lib64 packages that chroot needs to have a perfect behavior
was not included inside guest filesystem that I had created

When these pachages were included into /lib64 of the guest root filesystem
everything worked well.`  / Возможно Вы (или автообновление системы) что-то делали с /lib64? / Если честно, как конкретно восстанавливать в VmWare (перемонтировать диск к другой виртуалке и накатить там?) я не знаю.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это ошибка копирования.

Comment: @avp  Да, это решение я добавил ссылкой, и я не совсем его понимаю. Что именно он сделал? Автообновления системы не должно было быть.

Comment: @1d0, попробуйте создать ещё одну виртуальную машину на основе какого-нибудь live- или rescue-cd (64-битного), подключите к ней диск от проблемной вирт.машины и сделайте *chroot* в её корень. если пройдёт удачно, посмотрите с помощью `ldd`, какие библиотеки требуются, например, для `/sbin/load_policy`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не совсем понял, так? #chroot /run/media/liveuser/357f520e-d03a-4990-996b-06b24ac965bb /

Comment: если вы примонтировали корень диска проблемной машины в этот каталог с длинным названием, то, да, `chroot` вызывается именно так. если команда выполнится успешно, то внутри *chroot*-а попробуйте выполнить `ldd /sbin/load_policy` и вывод этой команды приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, он корень воспринимает, как команду? `chroot: failed to run command '/' : Permossion denied`

Comment: @1d0, вероятно, команду `chroot` вы попытались выполнить от непривилегированного пользователя.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, от рута, честно. `[root@localhost grub]# chroot /run/media/liveuser/357f520e-d03a-4990-996b-06b24ac965bb /`

Comment: @1d0, а у вас есть доступ к администрированию (VmWare vCenter или что-то в этом духе)?  / Т.е. для начала надо бы посмотреть, нет ли проблем с реальным физическим диском.

Comment: @1d0, понятно. посмотрите в man-е параметры программы `chroot`: `chroot newroot [command [arg] .. ]` — второй (и далее) параметр — выполняемая внутри *chroot*-а команда (и её аргументы). если команда не указана, выполняется `${SHELL} -i`

Comment: А этот юзер просто доставил `some /lib64 packages` (все же это не совсем ваш случай, у вас-то все работало, а потом вдруг сломалось).

Comment: @avp пространство диска подцеплено от СХД, были бы проблемы, я думаю было бы понятно =)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, т.е. `chroot /run/media/liveuser/357f520e-d03a-4990-996b-06b24ac965bb /bin/bash` должно отрабатывать и запускать оболочку из под которой можно выполнить `ldd /sbin/load_policy` .Верно?

Comment: да, есть надежда, что *shell* загрузится, хотя и небольшая, раз у вас проблемы с загрузкой библиотек.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin самое обидное, что не грузится. `[root@localhost /]# ls -la /run/media/liveuser/357f520e-d03a-4990-996b-06b24ac965bb /bin/ | grep bash  -rwx r-xr-x. 1 root root 938736 Apr 23 2012 bash  'lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Oct 23 2013 sh -> bash  chroot /run/media/liveuser/357f520e-d03a-4990-996b-06b24ac965bb /bin/bash  chroot: failed to run commans '/bin/bash': No such file or directory`  Где-то, что-то - я не понимать

Comment: @1d0, возможно, в ваших командах присутствуют опечатки, но в комментариях форматированный текст нечитабелен. добавляйте информацию в текст вопроса, пожалуйста.

Comment: если проблемы с загрузкой библиотек, то bash у вас не запустится. найдите пакет со статически собранным bash-ем в репозитории вашего дистрибутива, скачайте, распакуйте в какой-нибудь новый каталог в примонтированной файловой системе и попробуйте запустить с помощью chroot именно этот bash-static

Comment: @alexanderbarakin скрин добавил апдейтом в вопрос. Соответственно пути в тому же каталогу делаю через <TAB>. А strace может помочь? Или можно как-то при загрузке ядра сваливать этапы загрузки получить boot.log? Система не должна была обновляться и её никто не трогал в течении 5 месяцев. Кажется, это даже 1 перезагрузка была.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26921/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-1d0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, root раздел по одной папке из образа диска кидался в крашнутую систему.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего файловая система повреждена. Вам нужно любым образом получить доступ к диску не монтируя проблемную ФС, затем:

```
fsck -f /dev/sda2
```